# Java Searching through a String for a valid character sequence

Tags: java, string, validation, testing

I just took a codility test and was wondering why my solution only scored 37/100. The problem was that you were given a `String` and had to search through it for valid passwords.
Here are the rules:

1) A valid password starts with a capital letter and cannot contain any numbers. The input is restricted to any combination of a-z, A-Z and 0-9.

2)The method they wanted you to create is suppose to **return the size of the largest valid password**. So for example if you **input "Aa8aaaArtd900d"** the number 4 is suppose to be outputted by the solution method.  If no valid String is found the method should **return -1**

I cannot seem to figure out where I went wrong in my solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Also any suggestions on how to better test code for something like this would be greatly appreciated.

```
class Solution2 {
public int solution(String S) {
    int first = 0;
    int last = S.length()-1;
    int longest = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < S.length(); i++){
        if(Character.isUpperCase(S.charAt(i))){
        first = i;
        last = first;
        while(last < S.length()){
                 if(Character.isDigit(S.charAt(last))){
                    i = last;
                    break;
                    }
                 last++;
            }    
        longest = Math.max(last - first, longest);
        }
     }
    return longest;    
 }
}
```

**added updated solution, any thoughts to optimize this further?**

Comment: What does your code give instead of 4?

Comment: My code does give back 4.  The codility test did not like my answer for some reason.  It seemed to work fine when I was testing it.  My question was about where the program is failing.  The test claimed it only worked for 37% of the test cases.

Comment: If you were to indent your code correctly, it might be easier to spot the error.

Comment: Sorry, how does it look now?

Comment: Worse than when I edited it for you. Tip: If you ever have two closing `}` on adjacent lines with the same indent, you've not indented it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is too complicated. Since you are not asked to find the longest password, only the length of the longest password, there is no reason to create or store strings with that longest password. Therefore, you do not need to use `substring` or an array of `String`s, only `int` variables.

The algorithm for finding the solution is straightforward:

1. Make an `int pos = 0` variable representing the current position in `s`
2. Make a loop that searches for the next candidate password
3. Starting at position `pos`, find the next uppercase letter
4. If you hit the end of line, exit
5. Starting at the position of the uppercase letter, find the next digit
6. If you hit the end of line, stop
7. Find the difference between the position of the digit (or the end of line) and the position of the uppercase letter.
8. If the difference is above `max` that you have previously found, replace `max` with the difference
9. Advance `pos` to the position of the last letter (or the end of line)
10. If `pos` is under `s.length`, continue the loop at step 2
11. Return `max`.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/G5fSXQ)

Comment: I see what your saying, but you didn't really answer my original question.  The only difference between my algorithm and yours is the fact that you are directly returning the integer instead pulling the strings out and finding the longest one from that new list.  The implementation of finding valid passwords is almost identical.  The test stated performance did not mater and only getting the correct output was important.  I was kind of just wondering what in particular is causing my code to fail on the inputs they are testing.

Comment: @PhilDiMarco Your code has the silliest error of all - it returns `-1` instead of `0` when the password cannot be found. I think this is the smallest problem of your code, though. A bigger one is that is is very hard to read. For example, the part where you look for a digit can be simplified by using a `break`.

Comment: The problem asked for a -1 output for no valid password, I should of included that in my original post.  Using a break makes tons more sense thanks for the suggestion!